# NoneType error while using gae and gaesessions in python 2.7

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web.py

I recently attempted to migrate my GAE project from python2.5 to python2.7. Unfortunately, I have run into some issues with the required appengine_config.py file for gaesessions.

I can't tell if the issue is on GAE's part or sessions' part, but right now I think it's on sessions' side as I am able to print out the environ variable, but not the type of the my_start_response variable while toying around where the issue is.

Here is the issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 195, in Handle
    result = handler(dict(self._environ), self._StartResponse)
  File "d:\Documents\dna_manip\gaesessions\__init__.py", line 472, in __call__
    return self.app(environ, my_start_response)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Has anyone had to deal with this before? I feel like I goofed up while migrating the project.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I goofed up. When using web.py and python2.7 on google app engine, you need to use the application.wsgifunc() function, not application.cgirun()